# Removing duplicates from a list collection

Tags: c#

Hope someone can help me. I am using c# and I am somewhat new to it.
I am loading a text file into my app and splitting the data on "," I am reading part of string into a `<list>` when the data is read there is a lot of duplicates that vary depending on the txt file that I load.  Can someone tell me how to check the  and remove any and all duplicates that come up. There is no way of knowing what duplicates will show up as there is infinite possibilities that it could be.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 7):

If you are targeting .NET 3.5, use the Distinct extension method:

```
var deduplicated = list.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you load the strings into a `Set` instead of into a `List` then duplicates are discarded automatically.

Comment: Set sounds good - but I would check the strategy it uses for distinct.  Hopefully it is hashing with o(1) characteristics, if it uses list enumeration with o(n) - switch to using Dictionary<type,object> and use a null for a value instead.

Comment: My understanding is that it's hashing (and equivalent to a `Dictionary` of keys with no associated values).

Answer (score 2):

A simple/dirty example follows:

```
public List<string> RemoveDuplicates(List<string> listWithDups)
{
   cleanList = new List<string>();
   foreach (string s in listWithDups)
   {
      if (!cleanList.Contains(s))
         cleanList.Add(s);
   }
   return cleanList;
}
```

As a warning: String.Split on very large strings can cause consume huge amounts of memory and cause exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.kirupa.com/net/removingDuplicates.htm) an article with some examples and explanations in C#. Basically, you just keep track of the uniques, and check each element.

Alex

Comment: I am trying to do it this way but get a error that says "Error Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HKstats.Friendly>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)\Projects\HKstats\HKstats\stats.v1.01.cs