# Iterate over a collection and remove duplicates only if there are 2 or more of the specified item

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have a collection like this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> 
    {
      "One",
      "Two"
      "One",
      "Three",
      "One",
      "One"
    };
```

I want to remove those extra "Ones", leaving only the first "One" in.
The code below doesn't work somehow.

```
    foreach (var item in names)
        {
            if (names.Contains(item) && names.Count(x => x == item) > 1)
            {
                names.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

What are other, cleaner options? :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to check if it contains duplicates at all? This requirement would be pointless: "remove duplicates if there is only one item", so the title could be simplified with "remove duplicates". There are many duplicates like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517935/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-collection).

Comment: is it really necessary to remove the duplicates? there's a concept called "distinct" that iterates over a list and only returns you the existing values once!

Comment: `var distinctNames = new HashSet<string>(names)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
List<string> names = names.Distinct().ToList();
```